# Calculate New Height Based On New Width?

Tags: c#

I have a control whose width is 500 and height is 240, and I want to maintain the aspect ratio.

The control's width gets resized to 400.  What would the equation be the recalculate the new height?

Chris

Answer (score 9):

Algebra tells us it should be:

```
height = 400 * 240 / 500;
```

You can simplify this a bit by storing your aspect ratio

```
double ratio = 240 / 500;

// on resize
control.Height = (int)(control.Width * ratio);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this:

```
(Get ratio, 0.8 in this case) * Multiply by it
(New Width/ Old Width) * Old Height
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `newHeight = oldHeight/oldWidth*newWidth` with a few checks for divide by 0.

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase the question.

The control contains some content.  So if the width is decreased, the content is wrapped, so the height should now be adjusted to fit the content.  Is there a way to calculate the new height mathematically?

Sorry, maintaining aspect ration was not what I meant.

Chris

Comment: For example, let's say I had a textbox that contained the text "Test", and the textbox had a width of 75 and a height of 30, fitting the text perfectly.  If the width changed to 50, the text would be wrapped, and the height would have a new value.  How do you calulate the new height?

Comment: do you mean that the "textbox" actually has to get higher if the width gets smaller?

Comment: and are you really working with text and letters and lines - or with images? makes a huge difference..

Answer (score 0):

400 * 240 / 500

Answer (score 0):

```
float aspect = (float)original.Height / (float)original.Width;
int newHeight = (int)(newWidth * aspect);
```